# AngularJS Youtube player embed very big playlist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, youtube-api

I'm currently building an AngularJS app (I know it's kinda outdated but I'm confident with it so..).

My app need to embed a youtube player that contain a very big playlist (about 1500 items) but I can't code it so that it can embed more than 200 item actually.

I search all over the net and for month to fix that issue but none of what I read seems to work, I litteraly tried everthing I could think of.

Oh by the way I use angular-youtube-embed to make youtube api work with AngularJS.

Here is my code in the controller on how I build up the player

```
  const home = this;
  var inter = false;
  var playlistArray;
  var playListArrayLength;
  var maxNumber;
  var oldNumber = 0;
  var NewNumber = 0;
  home.playerVars = {
            list: 'LLRmPG23-ao586bxbZFPpvmw',
            rel : "0",
            loop : "1",
            origin : "http://www.youtube.com"
          };
    home.prsAction = function() {
      playlistArray = home.bestPlayer.getPlaylist();
      if (!inter){
          playlistArray = home.bestPlayer.getPlaylist();
          playListArrayLength = playlistArray.length;
          maxNumber = playListArrayLength;
          NewNumber = home.newRandomNumber();
          home.bestPlayer.setShuffle(playlistArray)
          home.bestPlayer.playVideoAt(home.newRandomNumber());
          //home.bestPlayer.playVideo();
        inter = true;
      }else if(inter){
        home.bestPlayer.stopVideo();
        inter = false;
      }
    }
  home.newRandomNumber = function() {
      oldNumber = NewNumber;
      NewNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNumber);
          return NewNumber;
  }
```

Some of thoses lines are here to make the player play a random video of the list with a bootstrap collapse effect on the player so don't pay attention to them.

And here is how I call the player in the HTML part

```
<youtube-video id="player" player-vars="home.playerVars" player="home.bestPlayer" ng-model="home.bestPlayer"></youtube-video>
```

I really need to make it work so if anyone as some idea don't hesitate.

I can make a plunkr or a fiddle to reproduced the case but since I don't have any error or anything but just a boring limit at 200 items, it's kinda useless.

Thank's in advance. *A desperate developer*

EDIT : I made a plunker that reproduced my actual problem/state on the player.

https://plnkr.co/edit/vNL0J4M2eR1P3C1IxfZs?p=preview

As you can see on it it load only 197 items in the player (I bieleve it was 199 some times ago but not sure).

As for where from the limit came from : for me it's definitly from the youtube iframe API (since i can't find anything about a limit in the angular-youtube-embed library).

EDIT 2 : In this link provided by google : https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?hl=fr when I put my playlist ID and try to load it, I have the same issue. I assum that this is definitly comming from youtube API and no solution for it. I'll try to code a workaround solution.

Comment: Helps to see the problem in action especially when it's a performance related question (which I think this is, but yea example would help).  There are lots of 'infinite' or 'virtual' scroller options out there but not entirely clear to me if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: You should be more precise on who sets this 200 item limit if you know it (or state that you don't if you don't, but from what you say it seems you know)

Comment: after your question and request I edit my post and you can find more informations. If I can precise anything else don't hesitate to ask ! I really need an answer so I will precise my question ^^

Comment: So nobody as the answer ? :/

Comment: @DylanTuna This is the URL of your playlist: [https://www.youtube.com/list_ajax?style=json&action_get_list=1&list=LLRmPG23-ao586bxbZFPpvmw](https://www.youtube.com/list_ajax?style=json&action_get_list=1&list=LLRmPG23-ao586bxbZFPpvmw); if you see closely, you'll see that the response has the same limit. If YouTube has such restriction/limit in their responses, there's not much you can do *(following this path, though)*, however *(even if is a little tedious)*, you can pass all the ids of the videos that belongs in the playlist.

Comment: @DylanTuna I did already tried with 228 videoIds and the response is the same: YouTube reset the video limit to 196. I tried with a playlist which has 1050 videos on it and the demo page shows 199. Another option could be load the playlist *(passing the videoIds instead the playlistId)*, or, create a array with the videoIds that are in the playlist you want play. The player will select a video *from the array* and it will play it.

Comment: @DylanTuna if you still looking for a solution to this, my advice is post a entry in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) - this is beyond Stack Overflow, this is a feature-request for YouTube and its API.