# YouTube player API calls onReady far too early for large playlists

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

The following code fails for large playlists:

```
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            height: '45vw',
            width: '80vw',
            playerVars: {
                listType: 'playlist',
                list: list,
                loop: 1,
                rel: 0
            },
            events: {
                onError: playerError,
                onReady: playerReady,
                onStateChange: playerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

function playerReady() {
        player.setShuffle(true);
        player.playVideoAt(0);
}
```

And this succeeds, though it very much depends on the browser so not ideal:

```
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            height: '45vw',
            width: '80vw',
            playerVars: {
                listType: 'playlist',
                list: list,
                loop: 1,
                rel: 0
            },
            events: {
                onError: playerError,
                onReady: playerReady,
                onStateChange: playerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

function playerReady() { setTimeout( function () {
        player.setShuffle(true);
        player.playVideoAt(0);},2000);
}
```

The player loads, but when the playlist is large (over 200 videos it seems), it appears to snip the playlist down to 200 entries. Before it does this `onReady` triggers, which in turn triggers `playerReady()` in my example. Unfortunately the player is not ready at this point so the function fails to do anything and no errors are reported. The delay allows the player to *actually* ready itself.

For reference:

`onReady: setTimeout( playerReady,2000 )`

This upsets the widgetapi, whatever that is, that seems to trigger also when onReady is called and complains in the console log.

Using `playeraddEventListener( "onReady", foo(bar) )` doesn't work either for the same reason. It also seems to block the retrieval of video information, because the player is not ready.

Comment: `it appears to snip the playlist down to 200 entries` - YouTube add such threshold. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55270038/4092887) I tried get all videos from a large playlist, but only the first 200 videos are loaded at once. You might post your question *(or search if a similar issue has been posted)* on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803).

Comment: I already know about the limit but that's not the issue I'm reporting. YouTube support pages said to post here, I didn't even know they had an issue tracker! Thanks for the link.